# Programmatically position UIView to right with full height in portrait & landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nslayoutconstraint

I have a tablet app I'm working on and I need to add a side panel that looks like a transparent overlay.  There are a couple different types of panels that will show up, so I have my main view laid out in a storyboard and am planning to pull in the panel from a .xib file.  Each panel is a custom class extended from a UIView.

The problem I have run into is how to add layout constraints.  I want the panel to sit on the right side, and fill the height of the ipad in both portrait and landscape mode.
This is easy in storyboards because I would just set constrains so that the bottom space = 0, trailing space = 0, & space to the nav bar = 0.  How do I do this programmatically?

So far, I tried creating an NSLayoutConstraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem:panel
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                        multiplier:1.0
                                        constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
```

The problem was, when I ran it, I got this error:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
>   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

& it broke my new constraint.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

edit:
I fixed my issue, here is the correct code for anyone else looking to do something similar:

```
//add panel from nib
HOTPanel *panel = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HOTPanel" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

panel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:panel];

//constraints
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:425.0f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint_width];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint_trailing];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint_top];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint_bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:panel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint_bottom];
```

Comment: Post the complete error. There must be information which constrains are set. Did you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to no on ``panel?

Comment: thanks for your help, but I just fixed my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Make it an answer and check it as the correct answer.